# Считать файл SWIFT

Tags: ios, файлы, swift

Есть приложение , где пользователь получает каждый день по одной строке  из файла. На данный момент я считываю рандомный индекс и показываю содержимое на label.
 КАК сделать так , что бы считывание началось с 1-й строки , и затем была 2,3  и когда конец файла , то  начать заново .

Есть сейчас вот такой код.

```
  func indexFileFunc()
{

    //Проверки
    if CurrentIndex.current == nil {
        //Показывать текст с индектом 0
        CurrentIndex.current = CurrentIndex(index: 0, day: CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()))
    } else if let currentIndex = CurrentIndex.current {
        //Проверка дня
        if currentIndex.day != CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()) {
            CurrentIndex.current = CurrentIndex(index: currentIndex.index + 1, day: CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()))
            //Что-бы был цикл посторения строк, то получать строку надо через остаток
           let maxCountString = 4 //число показывающее максимальное коллисетво строк
            let indexForText =  currentIndex % maxCountString //ОШИБКА!Binary operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CurrentIndex' and 'Int'

        }
    }
}


func readFile()
{

    // private let namePredictKey = "savePred"

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "two", ofType: "txt")

    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)

    let contentString = try! NSString(contentsOf: url, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    let  msgString = contentString.components(separatedBy: ".").first!.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: "")

        self.predictLabel.text = msgString
indexFileFunc()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, вам необходимо каждый день воспроизводить новую строку и строка должна меняется каждый день на следующую по списку?

Как устроен решение можно использовать UserDefaults и сохранять там индекс текущей строки и текущий ден из даты, и если день изменился то менять индекс и день.

Вот таким может быть пример!

Ответ не много усложнил для упрощения проверки.

```
struct CurrentIndex: Codable {
    var index = 0
    var day: Int!

    static func getDayInData(_ date: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
        return day
    }
    private enum Keys: String {
        case сurrentIndex = "сurrentIndex"
    }
    static var current: CurrentIndex? {
        get {
            guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: Keys.сurrentIndex.rawValue) else {
                return nil
            }
            return try? JSONDecoder().decode(CurrentIndex.self, from: data)
        }
        set {
            if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: Keys.сurrentIndex.rawValue)
            } else {
                UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: Keys.сurrentIndex.rawValue)
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
    }
}

//Проверки
if CurrentIndex.current == nil {
    //Показывать текст с индектом 0
    CurrentIndex.current = CurrentIndex(index: 0, day: CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()))
} else if let currentIndex = CurrentIndex.current {
    //Проверка дня
    if currentIndex.day != CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()) {
        CurrentIndex.current = CurrentIndex(index: currentIndex.index + 1, day: CurrentIndex.getDayInData(Date()))
     //Что-бы был цикл посторения строк, то получать строку надо через остаток
    let maxCountString = 4 //число показывающее максимальное коллисетво строк
    let indexForText = currentIndex % maxCountString //индекс строки

    }
}
```

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли вопрос, все как вы написали. Но я не совсем понимаю как этим кодом воспользоваться .

Comment: Напишите детально, что не понятно. После комментария проверки это реализация, все что выше отдельных файл.

Comment: Я сделал отдельный файл для struct CurrentIndex ,  и сделал отдельную функцию для проверки в классе где считываю файл. Не могу понять как правильно обьединить эти функции( проверки и считывание из файла). Я обновил код